# validate image with textbox value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to validate captcha image with user written textbox value.
Is it possible.?
here is some code what i have

```
   <div class="jr_captcha" style="float: left;">
   <img id="captcha"    src="http://xyz/cache/1396449675.0744.jpg" width="100" height="30"    style="border:0;" alt=" ">
   </div>
   <input name="data[Captcha][code]" id="code" type="text" class="jr_captcha_code" size="5" maxlength="5">
```

Here is image which shows up text which i would like to read.
     (not able to add because of reputation) but image look like **KkbLM**

Is it possible to do that.?
I don't have any idea how can i handle that.

NOTE:

--I'm working on joomla

--I cannot modify HTML or any coding behind component.

--I have to use javaScript, Jquery or backed PHP script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text on image cannot be read automatically. From your sample, the image is from http resource, find a way to retrieve the text on the image from same http source and store it in hidden field. This can then be compared with the textbox value.